# Unable to launch BizTalk admin console after BizTalk 2013 R2 CU1 install

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

The dev environment in our organization recently had the BizTalk CU patch installed. The existing version was BizTalk 2013 R2 and CU1 was installed over it.

After the upgrade the BizTalk admin console is not getting launched. The applications are running fine as some of them have been tested, however the following error pops up while trying to expand BizTalk group in the  Administrator:

> FX:{9A77C670-2FFD-4ab4-8F20-169C08FB8320}
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Exception Type : System.Null reference Exception
>
> Exception Stack Trace:
>
> at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExceptionMessageBox.BtsExceptionMessageBox.ReprocessManagementException(Exception exception, Exception newInnerException)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExceptionMessageBox.BtsExceptionMessageBox.ReprocessSpecificExceptions(Exception exception, Exception newInnerException)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExceptionMessageBox.BtsExceptionMessageBox.ReprocessExceptionRecursive(Exception exception)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.ExceptionMessageBox.BtsExceptionMessageBox..ctor(Exception exception, ExceptionMessageBoxButtons buttons, ExceptionMessageBoxSymbol symbol)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.SnapIn.Framework.FrameworkNotification.Show(Exception exception, String caption, MessageBoxButtons buttons, MessageBoxIcon icon, Control staMarshaller, IWin32Window parent)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.GroupNode.FullRefresh(Object o, ResultsChangedEventArgs e)
>      at Microsoft.BizTalk.Administration.SnapIn.GroupNode.OnExpand(AsyncStatus status)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.NodeSyncManager.ProcessRequest(NodeRequestInfo info, IRequestStatus requestStatus)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.NamespaceSnapInBase.ProcessRequest(Request request)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.SnapIn.ProcessRequest(Request request)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.SnapInClient.Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.IMessageClient.ProcessRequest(Request request)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Internal.IMessageClient.ProcessRequest(Request request)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.RequestStatus.BeginRequest(IMessageClient messageClient, RequestInfo requestInfo)
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.SnapInRequestOperation.ProcessRequest()
>      at Microsoft.ManagementConsole.Executive.Operation.OnThreadTransfer(SimpleOperationCallback callback)

Considering that it may be related to DTC, I restarted the DTC and WMI service and got the wirewall settings checked which seems to be fine. I also restarted the BizTalk box but that dint help.

Note -BizTalk and SQL are in different boxes and when I try connecting to the BizTalk group from another machine it does connect works fine from there.

Has anyone faced this issue, can you please highlight what might be a resolution to this?

Comment: Why are you installing CU1 rather than CU3 which is the latest cumulative update for BizTalk 2013 R2?  Someone with a similar issue with an earlier version of BizTalk.  Looks like it is MSDTC related.  https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/161ade80-47a0-49a8-ba0a-a51b464fb4b3/unhandled-exception-in-managed-code-snapin?forum=biztalkgeneral

Comment: Thanks for responding @Diijkgraaf,  actually it was a miscommunication with our infra team regarding which CU to install and we ended up having CU1.

Comment: Can you roll back your dev environment and get them to try CU3?

Comment: Before doing the roll back, I came across a post which  explained about the possible corruption of WMI namespace. 
This can be fixed by running the command - 
mofcomp "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\Bins32\BTSWMISchema.mof".
It did help and I could launch the BizTalk Admin Console after trying this out.
Please refer this for more details : http://stephenomo.blogspot.com/2014/10/null-reference-exception-when-trying-to.html
But agreed that CU1 might not be the best to install when CU3 is already available.

Comment: A good find.  Maybe put that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This specific issue post CU1 update in BizTalk 2013 R2 can be fixed by executing the following command which fixes the potential WMI namespace corruption during the upgrade  :

```
mofcomp "D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft BizTalk Server 2013\Bins32\BTSWMISchema.mof".
```

Please refer this for more details : [Null reference exception when trying to open the BTS admin console](https://stephenomo.blogspot.co.nz/2014/10/null-reference-exception-when-trying-to.html)…